# Implementing Ternary Conditional Operator in a List-Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, conditional-operator

I am trying to implement a ternary conditional operator in a list-comprehension. I have written it like this:

```
lst.append(dict2obj(item)) if type(item) is not in ['int'] else lst.append(item) for item in v
```

Where `lst` is empty list and `v` is another list with various elements. Editor is showing it syntactically incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `is` (no such keyword in Python to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: Sure there is. You can do `x is y`. It is `is in` that does not exist.

Comment: Using list comprehensions for calling functions inside is not easy to read, furthermore in a one-liner. Moreover, if `lst` is empty, @InbarRose' answer is clearly the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If you mean to write list comprehension you missed `[`, `]`:
- There is no `is not in` operator. Use `not in`.
- `type` function does not return `string`. Why not use `isinstance(item, int)`?

---

```
[lst.append(dict2obj(item)) if not isinstance(item, int) else lst.append(item)
 for item in v]
```

Use simple `for` loop if possible. It's more readable.

```
for item in v:
    if not isinstance(item, int)
        lst.append(dict2obj(item))
    else:
        lst.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did modify it like this but still it is showing it syntactically incorrect.

Comment: This will give a list of `None` since `list.append` does not return anything. Why would you want that?

Comment: @HannesOvrén When life gives you `None`s... hey, a free bunch of `None`s! Moreover, you'll have your `lst` made, which is why you'd probably want `list.append` (in a comprehension or beyond) or another of the many methods that mutate collections in place and return `None`.

Comment: @NunoAndré I don't have a problem with `list.append`, but with the use of list comprehension to do it. Unless the interpreter is smart enough to not compute the result of the list comprehension (which I doubt that CPython is) you are creating a potentially huge list that will require memory, but will never be used. It's also less readable, although I guess that is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

If the lst is empty from the start, you can simply create it like this:

```
lst = [dict2obj(item) if not isinstance(item, int) else item for item in v]
```

If you already have the list and want to add items, the proper way to do this in Python is to just extend the list you have with the new list:

```
lst.extend([dict2obj(item) if not isinstance(item, int) else item for item in v])
```

Or something like this (this uses an generator) to prevent extra overhead:

```
map(lst.append, (dict2obj(item) if not isinstance(item, int) else item for item in v))
```

Comment: `lst` is said to be empty, why not directly do something like `lst = [dict2obj(...)]`?

Answer (score 1):

I avoid mixing list comprehensions with ternary operators because it's too hard to understand what the function does at a glance.

I also try to use list comprehensions only for building up a list of return values. If I desire side-effects (such as adding items to a list), I will do this in a regular for-loop. This is especially true when I don't care about the list of return values. If you do go the route of a list comprehension, use the consume recipe for `itertools` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).
`consume((lst.append(dict2obj(item)) if not isinstance(item) else lst.append(item) for item in v), None)`

Here's how I'd solve this problem if I didn't do use @falsetru's approach (which is probably the easiest to read)

```
def convert(item):
    if not isinstance(item, int):
        result = dict2obj(item)
    else:
        result = item
    return result

lst.extend(map(convert, v)) #or itertools.imap
```

`convert` could be a lambda function if you're willing to trade compactness for readability.